# Erro ao Compilar Android - firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic3, gradle, android-gradle

Estou tendo problemas ao compilar o APK pelo ionic. Já removi o Android Studio e baixei novamente. Já removi e instalei novamente o Android. Mas não funcionou.

```
ionic cordova build android
```

**Retorna o seguinte erro:**

```
:app:preDebugBuild FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:15.+.
  Versions that do not match:
      16.0.1
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/D:/Aplicativos/iconexEntrega/platforms/android/app/libs/
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3 > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3 > com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date

BUILD FAILED in 5s
(node:2960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:15.+.
  Versions that do not match:
      16.0.1
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-api/maven-metadata.xml
      file:/D:/Aplicativos/iconexEntrega/platforms/android/app/libs/
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3 > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3
      project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3 > com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\Aplicativos\iconexEntrega\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

**Ionic Info:**

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 16 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.11.4 (D:\Programas\NodeJs\node.exe)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

**Gradle Projeto:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="25.0.2" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Gradle App:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1.0'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // Whether to append a 0 "abi digit" to versionCode when only a single APK is build 
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit')) {
        cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "../cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/mobile-cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle"
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-fcm/mobile-FCMPlugin.gradle"
apply from: "../phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/mobile-barcodescanner.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    //ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = project.ext.defaultCompileSdkVersion
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
    //ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = project.ext.defaultBuildToolsVersion
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = '../release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit == null ? false : cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : defaultMinSdkVersion
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    //This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
    //By default, we multiply the existing version code in the Android Manifest by 10 and 
    //add a number for each architecture.  If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
    //ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        flavorDimensions "default"

        productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
        // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

/*
 * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
 * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
 * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
 */


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
      if(['validateReleaseSigning', 'validateSigningRelease', 'validateSigningArmv7Release', 'validateSigningX76Release'].contains(task.name)) {
         promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
      }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

Comment: Pedro, alguma novidade com relação a esse problema? To enfrentando ele também

Comment: Em SDK Tools, veja se está instalado o "Google  Play Services".

Comment: Está instalado. O erro continua acontecendo